# Flex datagrid not storing values in arraycollection for multiselect option

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

I have the following datagrid:

```
<controls:MDataGrid id="holdrules_datagrid" width="100%" height="100%"
                                      allowMultipleSelection="true" dataProvider="{holdRuleDataList.holdRuleDataList}" >
```

I am trying to get all the selected rows from this, but the value is not getting stored, and is giving me `null` in the Java layer

```
var arr:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection;
arr = holdrules_datagrid.selectedItems as ArrayCollection
```

Can anyone please help me with what is wrong here?

Comment: <controls:MDataGrid id="holdrules_datagrid" width="100%" height="100%"
           allowMultipleSelection="true" dataProvider="{holdRuleDataList.holdRuleDataList}" >

Answer (score 0):

DataGrid.selectedItems is an Array, not an ArrayCollection.  If you want an ArrayCollection you'll something like:

`arr.source = holdrules_datagrid.selectedItems;`

This may still not be quite what you want.  I haven't tried this myself, but I believe that this will just reference `selectedItems`, so if the selection changes then `arr` would also be updated.  If you want a copy of the selection at the time of selection, you'll need a copy of the array:

`arr.source = holdRules_datagrid.selectedItems.slice();`